# Deserializing LongMap in Kryo

Tags: scala, serialization, kryo

I have a class with a field of `scala.collection.mutable.LongMap` type.

After serializing it with `Kryo` I attempt to deserialize the object and get the following exception:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final scala.collection.mutable.LongMap field com.name.of.field to scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
Serialization trace:
field (com.name.of)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:626) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729) ~[com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo-2.21.jar:na]
```

IIUC the `LongMap` is serialized as `HashMap` and then deserialization fails as the `HashMap` can't be written to the `LongMap` field.

I manually ran something like https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/romix/scala/serialization/kryo/MapSerializerTest.scala#L78 and confirmed that serialized `LongMap` is deserialized into a `HashMap`.

Any idea how to properly read/write this Object so the `LongMap` will be read as `LongMap` instead of `HashMap`?

Do I need to use a proxy class? write a custom serializer/deserializer?
Alternatively, is there a decent serialization library that handles `LongMap`s properly?

P.S. I would have tagged the question with `LongMap` but I don't have enough reputation to create new tags.

Comment: show your class definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a custom serializer. There is https://github.com/twitter/chill#serializers-for-scala-classes which includes serializers for some types in Scala standard library, but apparently not for `LongMap` (you may already be using this library, perhaps indirectly). Look at how they do it and write your own.

However, this error shouldn't happen by default. Look for `Kryo#register` and `Kryo#setDefaultSerializer` calls in your code (or code you call): are you telling Kryo to serialize/deserialize all `scala.collection.mutable.Map`s as `HashMap`s?

Comment: Thanks, writing a custom serializer for LongMap solved it.
I didn't explicitly called `Kryo#register` nor `Kryo#setDefaultSerializer` and didn't instruct Kryo to serialize/deserialize `Map`s as `HashMap`s. I assume that's its default behavior.